# Create a JTable using an ArrayList of "n" AbstractDrawablePoints

Tags: java, swing, dictionary, object, jtable

I have an `ArrayList<AbstractDrawablePoint> nodePoints` which changes dynamically/can have anywhere from 1 to n number of points within it.

I would like to have a JTable fill dynamically based on the number of points within nodePoints. Currently, I can hardcode an `Object [][]` to do so like the following:

```
    String[] columnNames = {"u", "v"};
    Object[][] nodeData = new Object[][] {
         {nodePoints.get(0).getU(), nodePoints.get(0).getV() },
         {nodePoints.get(1).getU(), nodePoints.get(1).getV() }
    };
    
    JTable table = new JTable(nodeData, columnNames);
```

However, I would like to fill `nodeData` dynamically instead of hard coding like I did.

Comment: Not a problem. Use `DefaultTableModel` with the zero rows and column names present ctor. Then you can call `dtm.addRow()`

Comment: I'd prefer a custom `TableModel`, but g00se's comment will also work nicely

Comment: You can also use a Vector of Vectors to create the DefaultTableModel. The model actually converts your 2D array to a Vector of Vectors anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @g00se's answer I came up with the following:

```
String[] columnNames = {"u", "v"};

DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,0);

for (AbstractDrawablePoint node: nodePoints) {
    Object [] currentNode = {node.getU(),node.getV()};          
    tableModel.addRow(currentNode);
}


JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```